# Java GUI use one button to add multiple text fields to a text file?

Tags: java, user-interface

I have to create a GUI that takes the input for multiple text fields, and when the user clicks one button, it adds all of the input to a text file. All the text fields will have to do with all the parts of an mp3 file. (artist/album, etc) Then, once the mp3 files are added to the text file, I have to create a button to edit or delete them. I'm confused as to how to make an "add" button for multiple text fields. Here is what I have so far:

```
public musicLib()
{
    setLayout(new FlowLayout());

    // Song Row
    itemLabel = new JLabel("Item Code: ");
    add(itemLabel);
    itemCode = new JTextField(10);
    add(itemCode);
    descriptionLabel = new JLabel("Description: ");
    add(descriptionLabel);
    description = new JTextField(10);
    add(description);
    artistLabel = new JLabel("Artist: ");
    add(artistLabel);
    artist = new JTextField(10);
    add(artist);
    albumLabel = new JLabel("Album: ");
    add(albumLabel);
    album = new JTextField(10);
    add(album);


    // Buttons
    addButton = new JButton("Add");
    add(addButton);
    Event e = new Event(); error"no suitable constructor found"
    addButton.addActionListener(e); // error"incompatible types"

    addButton.addActionListener(new ActionListener() 
    {
    String nl = "\n",
    data = "";


public void dataWriter(String data, String fileName) throws IOException {
File file = getFileStreamPath(fileName); // error"cannot find symbol"

if (!file.exists()) {
   file.createNewFile();
}

FileOutputStream writer = openFileOutput(file.getName(),   Context.MODE_PRIVATE); // error"cannot find symbol"

for (String string: data) // error"for- each not applicable to expression type"
{
    writer.write(string.getBytes());
    writer.flush();
}

writer.close();
}








}
```

Thank you guys very much for your help. I just need some help getting the one button to add multiple text field inputs to the text file. Thanks in advance!

Comment: You're referring to http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/EditText.html , correct? : )

Comment: @Sipty i don't believe so, I'm not working with android, just making a Java application.

Comment: Ah! I Just noticed the tags, apologies! My answer still holds, but you would need to replace edit text, with your text field. If you can give me links to the classes you're using, I'm sure I can whip up a more accurate answer.

Comment: @Sipty just updated the code!

Comment: Seems to me like everything is in place, apart from the text extraction of multiple fields bit. Or am I misunderstand your code? (Has been a while since I've worked with pure Java, apologies! D:)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This chunk, will be a part of the initial gui setup function:

```
/**
 * On click listener for the add button
 */
addButton.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
    String nl = "\n",
        data = "";
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ae){
        data += "Label: " + albumLabel.getText() + nl;
        data += "Artist: " + albumArtist.getText() + nl;
        /*
         * Repeat the same for any other text fields you have
         */
        dataWriter(data, "test.txt");

    } 
 });
```

And here is your file writer:

```
public void dataWriter(String data, String fileName) {
    File file = getFileStreamPath(fileName);

    if (!file.exists()) {
       file.createNewFile();
    }

    FileOutputStream writer = openFileOutput(file.getName(), Context.MODE_PRIVATE);

    for (String string: data){
        writer.write(string.getBytes());
        writer.flush();
    }

    writer.close();
}
```

Comment: I had a Java implementation ready for this, but discarded it, since I thought your updated code would work. Let me try to recreate and update it for you.

Comment: You may want to add a newline character to the end of each data addition so that the text file is formatted. This would work, however, would have all the text on one line.

Comment: I updated it to be more Java friendly, please test and let me know how it works. My memory is rusty, but the only real android/java difference is adding the listener and getting the text out of the field. Everything else is the same.

Comment: @Sipty thank you so much, sorry for being so confused, but where exactly would this code snippet go inside my code?

Comment: The listener would be a part of the initial gui setup. The writer code, at the end, would be put in a different function, which is called once the reading is complete, allow me to edit this in for you.

Comment: I'm trying to implement it now, I will let you know how it works! Thank you very much ! @Sipty

Comment: I have a few error messages, I will post what my current code looks like, and comment where the errors are.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/86910/discussion-between-paul-and-sipty).

Answer (score 1):

If I correctly understand you, you want something like that;

```
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
sb.append("ItemLabel: "+itemLabel.getText()+"\n");
sb.append("Description: "+description.getText()+"\n");
```

and add what you need. When you write to file

```
out.write(sb.toString());
```

Comment: thank you for this answer, how would I incorporate this into my code?

Answer (score 1):

I wrote this very quick program to read and write field data using a `Map` of fields. The map consists of components and metadata on how to lay it out and whether its information is exportable or not.

It is far from complete, but with a little file IO, you can store and retrieve information and send it to the form as long as the incoming data matches the "schema" defined in the applications parsing logic.

### Figure 1

Window after the "Edit" button is clicked.

[image]

### Figure 2

Output after all fields' data has been exported to text; using the "Add" button.

## Code

[image]

```
import java.awt.GridBagConstraints;
import java.awt.GridBagLayout;
import java.awt.Insets;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.util.Iterator;
import java.util.LinkedHashMap;
import java.util.Map;

import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JComponent;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JTextField;
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;
import javax.swing.text.JTextComponent;

public class MusicApp extends JPanel {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 6555747177061710030L;
    private static final String APP_TITLE = "Music App";
    private static final int APP_WIDTH = 800;
    private static final int APP_HEIGHT = 600;

    private static class GridItem {
        private JComponent component;
        private boolean isExportable;
        private int xPos;
        private int yPos;
        private int colSpan;
        private int rowSpan;

        public GridItem(JComponent component, boolean isExportable, int xPos, int yPos) {
            this(component, isExportable, xPos, yPos, 1, 1);
        }

        public GridItem(JComponent component, boolean isExportable, int xPos, int yPos, int colSpan, int rowSpan) {
            this.component = component;
            this.isExportable = isExportable;
            this.xPos = xPos;
            this.yPos = yPos;
            this.colSpan = colSpan;
            this.rowSpan = rowSpan;
        }
    }

    private int appWidth;
    private int appHeight;
    private Map<String, GridItem> componentMap;
    private GridBagLayout layout;
    private GridBagConstraints constraints;

    public MusicApp(int width, int height) {
        super();

        this.appWidth = width;
        this.appHeight = height;

        this.init();
        this.createChildren();
    }

    protected void init() {
        this.constraints = new GridBagConstraints();
        this.layout = new GridBagLayout();
        this.componentMap = new LinkedHashMap<String, GridItem>();

        // Disable size for now.
        //this.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(appWidth, appHeight));

        this.setLayout(this.layout);

        this.constraints.ipadx = 3;
        this.constraints.ipady = 3;
        this.constraints.insets = new Insets(8, 4, 8, 4);

        //JLabel itemLabel, descriptionLabel, artistLabel, albumLabel, priceLabel;
        //JTextField itemCode, description, artist, album, price;
        //JButton addButton,editButton, deleteButton;

        this.constraints.anchor = GridBagConstraints.LAST_LINE_END;

        componentMap.put("itemLabel", new GridItem(new JLabel("Item"), false, 0, 0, 3, 1));

        this.constraints.fill = GridBagConstraints.HORIZONTAL;

        componentMap.put("artistLabel", new GridItem(new JLabel("Artist"), false, 0, 1));
        componentMap.put("artistText", new GridItem(new JTextField(), true, 1, 1, 2, 1));

        componentMap.put("albumLabel", new GridItem(new JLabel("Album"), false, 0, 2));
        componentMap.put("albumText", new GridItem(new JTextField(), true, 1, 2, 2, 1));

        componentMap.put("priceLabel", new GridItem(new JLabel("Price"), false, 0, 3));
        componentMap.put("priceText", new GridItem(new JTextField(), true, 1, 3, 2, 1));

        componentMap.put("descriptionLabel", new GridItem(new JLabel("Description"), false, 0, 4));
        componentMap.put("descriptionText", new GridItem(new JTextField(20), true, 1, 4, 2, 1));

        componentMap.put("addButton", new GridItem(new JButton("Add"), false, 0, 5));
        componentMap.put("editButton", new GridItem(new JButton("Edit"), false, 1, 5));
        componentMap.put("deleteButton", new GridItem(new JButton("Delete"), false, 2, 5));

        ((JButton) componentMap.get("addButton").component).addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                System.out.println(grabFieldData());
            }
        });;

        ((JButton) componentMap.get("editButton").component).addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                String[] lines = {
                    "artistText: Led Zeppelin",
                    "albumText: Houses of the Holy",
                    "priceText: 12.99",
                    "descriptionText: The fifth studio album by British rock band Led Zeppelin, released by Atlantic Records on 28 March 1973."
                };

                setFieldData(lines);
            }
        });;

        ((JButton) componentMap.get("deleteButton").component).addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                clearFieldData();
            }
        });;

    }

    protected void createChildren() {
        Iterator<Map.Entry<String, GridItem>> it;

        for (it = componentMap.entrySet().iterator(); it.hasNext();) {
            Map.Entry<String, GridItem> item = it.next();
            GridItem gridItem = item.getValue();

            this.constraints.gridx = gridItem.xPos;
            this.constraints.gridy = gridItem.yPos;
            this.constraints.gridwidth = gridItem.colSpan;
            this.constraints.gridheight = gridItem.rowSpan;

            this.add(gridItem.component, this.constraints);
        }
    }

    private String grabFieldData() {
        StringBuffer buff = new StringBuffer();
        Iterator<Map.Entry<String, GridItem>> it;

        for (it = componentMap.entrySet().iterator(); it.hasNext();) {
            Map.Entry<String, GridItem> item = it.next();
            GridItem gridItem = item.getValue();

            if (gridItem.isExportable) {
                if (gridItem.component instanceof JTextComponent) {
                    buff.append(item.getKey()).append(": ")
                        .append(((JTextComponent) gridItem.component).getText())
                        .append("\n");
                }
            }
        }

        return buff.toString();
    }

    private void clearFieldData() {
        Iterator<Map.Entry<String, GridItem>> it;
        for (it = componentMap.entrySet().iterator(); it.hasNext();) {
            Map.Entry<String, GridItem> item = it.next();
            GridItem gridItem = item.getValue();

            if (gridItem.isExportable) {
                if (gridItem.component instanceof JTextComponent) {
                    ((JTextComponent) gridItem.component).setText("");
                }
            }
        }
    }

    private void setFieldData(String[] textLines) {
        clearFieldData();

        for (String line : textLines) {
            String[] values = line.split(":\\s*");

            if (values.length == 2) {
                GridItem gridItem = componentMap.get(values[0]);

                if (gridItem.isExportable && gridItem.component instanceof JTextComponent) {
                    JTextComponent field = ((JTextComponent) gridItem.component);
                    field.setText(values[1]);
                    field.setCaretPosition(0);
                }
            }
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                JFrame f = new JFrame(APP_TITLE);

                f.setContentPane(new MusicApp(APP_WIDTH, APP_HEIGHT));
                f.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
                f.pack();
                f.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
                f.setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much for such a detailed answer! It might be a little too advanced for my current standing, but I will take a look! Thanks! @Mr. Polywhirl